# How to count how many times a letter appear in a text javascript

Tags: javascript

i am trying to count how many times a letter appear in a string. This is my code:

```
var myFunc = function(inside) {
    count = 0; 
    for (var i=0;i<inside.length;i++) {
        if(inside[i]==="a") {
            count+=1;
            }
        return count;
    };
};
console.log(myFunc("hai, okay"));
```

Comment: And your problem is...?

Comment: Why is return count inside the for loop?

Comment: what is the output ?

Comment: Just to clarify, are you looking for the length (number of characters in a string) or how many characters in a string are actual letters (A - Z) and nothing else (numbers, special characters, etc)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var myFunc = function(inside) {
    count = 0; 
    for (var i=0;i<inside.length;i++) {
        if(inside[i]=="a") {
            count+=1;
            }
        //return should not come here
    };
    return count;

};
console.log(myFunc("hai, okay"));
```

or u can use this also

```
var myFunc = function(inside) {
        return (inside.match(new RegExp("a", "g"))).length;
    }
console.log(myFunc("hai, okay"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not giving correct result since it has a return statement inside a for loop so it will return after first iteration and will return `0`. You can simply put the return outside for loop to make it work.

You can also simply change your method to

```
var myFunc = function(inside, character) 
{
    return inside.split( character ).length - 1;
};
console.log(myFunc("hai, okay"), "a");
```

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
var countAs = inside.replace(/[^a]/g, '').length;
```

Reason: elminate all char's unwanted and take the length of the rest.

Warpped:

```
function howMany(inside, theChar)
{
    var reg = new RegExp("[^" + theChar + "]","g");
    return inside.replace(reg, '').length;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How many letters? As in "Abba" would be 2 letters, namely "a" and "b"?

```
var letter_counts = function(txt) {
    var res = {};
    for (var i=0;i<txt.length;i++) {
        var c = txt[i].toLowerCase();
        res[c] = ( res[c] ? res[c] : 0 ) + 1;
    };
    return res;
};

var letter_cnts = letter_counts("Abba");
// Object {a: 2, b: 2}

letter_cnts["a"]; // == 2
letter_cnts["b"]; // == 2
```